# Error with flush, try catch and object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

It is throwing an error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'complete' cannot be null

How do I "tell" the Entity Manager not to consider the fruit object since it is throwing an error?

I have an object like:

```
class Fruit {
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /** @Column(type="string", length=10, nullable=true) */
    private $name;

    /** @Column(type="boolean") */
    private $complete;

    /* Omitted to make it simple */
}
```

And a method like:

```
public function uploadAction(){
    try{
       /* Omitted to make it simple */
       while ($data = fgetcsv($fic, 1024, $delimiter)) {
           try {
               $fruit = $fruitManager->createFruit($data);
               $outcome_fruit = $fruit->id;
           } catch (\Exception $e) {
               $outcome_details[] = $e->getMessage();
           }
       }

       fclose($fic);
       @unlink($file_path);

       $csv_data = $this->view->io->build_csv_file($outcome_details);
       $csv_import->output_csv = base64_encode(gzencode($csv_data));
       $this->em->persist($csv_import);

       // error here
       $this->em->flush();
       //

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
       print $e->getMessage();
       exit;
    }
}
```

My fruitManager

```
class FruitManager{
   public function createFruit($name){
      $fruit = new \Entities\Fruit;
      $fruit->name = $name;

      throw new Exception("Exception.");

      $fruit->complete = 1;
      $this->em->persist($fruit);
      $this->em->flush();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have few options:

- update your entity allowing null values using ORM to allow null values for this field ie `/** @Column(type="boolean", nullable=true) */`
- update your entity with default value using ORM ie `/** @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false, options={"default" : false}) */`
- assign default value in the entity constructor
- assign default value using `private $complete = false;` like Freelancer said

I'd prefer one of the first 2 options depending on logic needs.
Thanks.

Comment: but, I don't want to save the fruit once it is throwing an error. Is there another way when the error occurs I discard the object?

Comment: well.. you already have this code in place: if Exception occurs fruit not saved and you go to the catch block. Do you have any issues with it?

Answer (score 0):

try by setting  `private $complete = false;` or true as you want.

Comment: but, I mean I don't want to save the fruit once it is throwing a error. How can I "tell" to flush that I want to persist only $csv_import object.

Comment: well it's very dirty but you could try to detach your object fruit before to flush: $em->detach($fruit); But I would suggest you to find a better logic instead of  doing this.

Comment: I agree, but I tried out of curiosity and it still gives the same error.